# Haskell: How can I set polymorphic types of arguments and return types

Tags: haskell

I want to define a set of functions in polymorphic type of arguments and return types, just as below.

```
class Poly a b where
  poly :: a -> b

instance Poly Int Int where
  poly :: Int -> Int
  poly a = a
```

When I test it in ghci, using `poly 3 :: Int` and then it gives me errors:

```
*Poly> poly 3 :: Int

<interactive>:486:1: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘poly’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Poly a0 Int)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instance exist:
        instance Poly Int Int
          -- Defined at OneFunctionManyArguments.hs:10:10
    • In the expression: poly 3 :: Int
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = poly 3 :: Int

<interactive>:486:6: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from the literal ‘3’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Num a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
        instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        ...plus two others
        ...plus 46 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘poly’, namely ‘3’
      In the expression: poly 3 :: Int
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = poly 3 :: Int
```

When I use `poly (3 :: Int) :: Int`, it returns me the right value `3`...
I would like to know how to get rid of the tedious `:: Int` declaration?

Comment: You can’t.  Unless you use FunctionalDependencies.

Comment: @augustss Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the type of `poly`? Right now nothing keeps you (or some random library) from adding e.g. a `Poly Double Int` instance, which is why the type of `3` in `poly 3` is ambiguous.

You could do

```
instance Poly a where
    poly :: a -> a
```

That would nail down the type of `poly 3 :: Int`, but it would make `poly` less general.

You could enable `FunctionalDependencies` and do

```
instance Poly a b | b -> a where
    poly :: a -> b
```

Then `poly 3 :: Int` would be OK, because `b` is declared as uniquely determining `a`.

You could also enable `TypeFamilies` and use an associated type:

```
class Poly b where
    type Arg b :: *
    poly :: Arg b -> b

instance Poly Int where
    type Arg Int = Int
    poly x = x
```

Again, this lets ghc derive the argument type from the result type, so `poly 3 :: Int` typechecks.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I want.